# Strange requests from VPS IP address

Tags: vps

In the Apache logs, I found out that strange requests are coming from the IP address of my VPS, which I did not make. Usually, requests from my VPS that I run through the CRON scheduler are as follows.

`domain.ru:443 **.**.**.** - - [20/Sep/2021:19:55:01 +0300] "GET /test.php HTTP/1.0" 200 421 "-" "Wget/1.19.4 (linux-gnu)" 118650`

**Strange queries look like this**

`domain.ru:80 **.**.**.** - - [21/Sep/2021:09:06:52 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-" 48`

`domain.ru:80 **.**.**.** - - [21/Sep/2021:08:10:59 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-" 53`

`domain.ru:80 **.**.**.** - - [21/Sep/2021:07:27:17 +0300] "GET /boaform/admin/formLogin?username=adminisp&psd=adminisp HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-" 51`

`domain.ru:80 **.**.**.** - - [21/Sep/2021:06:25:03 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-" 145`

`domain.ru:80 **.**.**.** - - [21/Sep/2021:04:11:17 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-" 41`

`domain.ru:80 **.**.**.** - - [21/Sep/2021:02:52:44 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-" 41`

`domain.ru:80 **.**.**.** - - [21/Sep/2021:02:36:17 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-" 41`

`domain.ru:80 **.**.**.** - - [21/Sep/2021:01:51:52 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0" 38`

**These requests are especially alarming.**

`domain.ru:80 **.**.**.** - - [21/Sep/2021:07:27:17 +0300] "GET /boaform/admin/formLogin?username=adminisp&psd=adminisp HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-" 51`

`domain.ru:80 **.**.**.** - - [21/Sep/2021:01:51:52 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0" 38`

`domain.ru:80 **.**.**.** - - [20/Sep/2021:19:51:34 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "YahooBot" 54`

As you can see, UserAgent YahooBot and Mozilla / 5.0 are transmitted, and even a strange request to the page /boaform/admin/formLogin?username=adminisp&psd=adminisp

Tell me what to do. Is it a virus?

Answer (score 5):

These are bots probing for vulnerabilities.  I suggest you modify LogFormat to include the client IP in case you want to block those.  Here is what I use:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %B \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Here is the relevant [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html) for LogFormat variables.  If you want, the next step is to block abuse traffic.  I use fail2ban for that.  Consider enabling the [unique_id](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_unique_id.html) module, that way you can log that id in both access and error log.

Comment: My log has the following format "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %{us}T", everything is configured correctly as I understand it.

Comment: Are these bots just scanning random IP ranges or is there some corporate/geometric determination to IP's and thus some logic to being targeted?

Comment: @EricBallard They probably scan everything they can.